# excel vba_specify special character then split to different row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet like below

> DATA_DT   G_GLACNO_OLD    G_GLACCTNO
>
> 4/30/2017 1150007000  130134001L01 / L02 / L03 / L50
>
> 4/30/2017 1151009000  130150901L01 / L02 / L03 / L50
>
> 4/30/2017 1151014026  130154602L01 / L02 / L03 / L50
>
> 4/30/2017 1151014027  130154602L01 / L02 / L03 / L50
>
> 4/30/2017 1151015003  130154701L01 / L02 / L03 / L50
>
> 4/30/2017 1151015004  130154701L01 / L02 / L03 / L50
>
> 4/30/2017 1151015006  130154701L01 / L02 / L03 / L50
>
> 4/30/2017 1178036000  130974003L01 / L02 / L03 / L30 / L50
>
> 4/30/2017 1151015011  130154701L01 / L02 / L03 / L50
>
> 4/30/2017 1151015001  130154702L01 / L02 / L03 / L50
>
> 4/30/2017 1151015002  130154702L01 / L02 / L03 / L50

I would like split the row by the special character "/"

so

> > 4/30/2017   1150007000  130134001L01 / L02 / L03 / L50

i want to become

> 4/30/2017 1150007000 130134001L02
>
> 4/30/2017 1150007000 130134001L03
>
> 4/30/2017 1150007000 130134001L50
>
> 4/30/2017 1150007000 130134001L01

Is there any quick solution?

> 4/30/2017 1150007000  130134001L01 / L02 / L03 / L50

There are some rows have 4 slashes, some rows have 5 slashes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Comment: look at `split` and looping through array

Comment: the solution is as quick as it takes you to write the code

Comment: Thanks you Ralph.  I should mention more about my tring.

Answer (score 0):

However, as far as __________________________ (put any random thing here), I have decided to give it a try on your input-output:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()
    
    Debug.Print RemoveSomeSlashed("4/30/2017 1151015004 130154701L01 / L02 / L03 / L50")
    Debug.Print RemoveSomeSlashed("4/30/2017 11780 130974003L01 / L02 / L03 / L30 / L50")
    
End Sub

Public Function RemoveSomeSlashed(myInput As String) As String
    
    Dim cnt         As Long
    Dim startCnt    As Long
    Dim endCnt      As Long
    Dim compare     As String
    
    compare = Replace(myInput, "/", "")
    endCnt = Len(myInput) - Len(compare) - 2
    
    For cnt = Len(myInput) To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(myInput, cnt, 1) = "/" Then
            Mid(myInput, cnt, 1) = "?"
            startCnt = startCnt + 1
            If startCnt = endCnt Then
                RemoveSomeSlashed = Replace(myInput, "?", "")
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next cnt
    
End Function
```

That is not the best solution, but it works. The idea is that it removes all the slashes but two and you are not allowed to have the `?` sign in the string.

As a bonus, it will display empty string if your text does not have at least `3` slashes :).